# Why doesn't this grid layout work? Specifically: Why are the nested items arranged in rows and not placed on grid?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid layout, such that there are 5 equal spaced columns, and 6 rows, 3 of the rows contain a header with the name of the row beneath, which is a section full of items (think 250x250 pixel squares filling each section is the result i'm aiming for).

Stylesheet looks like (in sass):

```
    .offerings-index-grid-wrapper
    {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 25px auto 25px auto 25px auto;

        max-width: 100vw;


     }

    .offerings-index-grid-category
    {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 5;

        &.cat1
        {
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 2;
        }

        &.cat2
        {
            grid-row-start: 3;
            grid-row-end: 4;
        }

        &.cat3
        {
        grid-row-start: 5;
        grid-row-end: 6;
    } }


    .offerings-index-grid-offeringssection
    {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 5;

        &.sect1
        {
            grid-row-start: 2;
            grid-row-end: 3;
        }

        &.sect2
        {
            grid-row-start: 4;
            grid-row-end: 5;
        }

        &.sect3
        {
            grid-row-start: 6;
            grid-row-end: 7;
        }
    }

    .offerings-index-grid-offering
    {
        display: flex;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $offering-link-text-color;

        -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
        column-span: 1;

        &.offerings-index-grid-offering:focus
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $offering-link-text-color;
        }

        &.offerings-index-grid-offering:visited
        {
            text-decoration: none;
           color: $offering-link-text-color;
        }

        &.offerings-index-grid-offering:hover
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $offering-link-text-color-hover;
        }

        &.offerings-index-grid-offering:active
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $offering-link-text-color;
    } }
```

Here is the view:

```css
.offerings-index-grid-wrapper {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 25px auto 25px auto 25px auto;
      grid-template-rows: 25px auto 25px auto 25px auto;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 1275px;
}

.offerings-index-grid-category {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
      grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.offerings-index-grid-category.cat1 {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
      grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.offerings-index-grid-category.cat2 {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
      grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.offerings-index-grid-category.cat3 {
  -ms-grid-row: 5;
      grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offeringssection {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
      grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offeringssection.sect1 {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
      grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offeringssection.sect2 {
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
      grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offeringssection.sect3 {
  -ms-grid-row: 6;
      grid-row-start: 6;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offering {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #527b52;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  -webkit-column-span: 1;
          column-span: 1;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offering.offerings-index-grid-offering:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #527b52;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offering.offerings-index-grid-offering:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #527b52;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offering.offerings-index-grid-offering:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #459745;
}

.offerings-index-grid-offering.offerings-index-grid-offering:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #527b52;
}
```

```html
<div class="offerings-index-grid-wrapper">
            <div class="offerings-index-grid-category cat1">
                <h3>Category1</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="offerings-index-grid-offeringssection sect1">
                <a href="" class="offerings-index-grid-offering">
                    Hey I'm an offering!
                    <img class="offering-image" src=\svg\Example.svg>
                </a>

                <a href="" class="offerings-index-grid-offering">
                    Hey I'm an offering!
                    <img class="offering-image" src=\svg\Example.svg>
                </a>

                <a href="" class="offerings-index-grid-offering">
                    Hey I'm an offering!
                    <img class="offering-image" src=\svg\Example.svg>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="offerings-index-grid-category cat2">
                <h3>Category2</h3>
            </div >

            <div class="offerings-index-grid-offeringssection sect2">
                <a href="" class="offerings-index-grid-offering">
                    Hey I'm an offering!
                    <img class="offering-image" src=\svg\Example.svg>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="offerings-index-grid-category cat3">
                <h3>Category3</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="offerings-index-grid-offeringssection sect3">
                <a href="" class="offerings-index-grid-offering">
                    Hey I'm an offering!
                    <img class="offering-image" src=\svg\Example.svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I end up with is something that looks like this:

```
Category1
item 1
item 2
item 3
Category2
item 1
Category3
item 1
```

But I am trying to get this:

```
Category1
item 1 item 2 item 3
Category2
item 1
Category3
item 1
```

Also concerningly, when inspecting in browser, it looks like the categories and sub sections are not a part of the grid at all. (They do not show the two classes .offerings-index-grit-category or .offerings-index-grid-offeringssection)

Comment: You're right about this last one. Only direct childs are parts of your grid.
Why do you need 5 rows? Isn't 3 enough (item1 item 2 item3)? Also what's your goal exactly, do you have an image of how you want it to look like?

Comment: I want 3 main rows that I could use to populate with items from the database, and I wanted rows in between them just for the heading of each of those. The goal is to have a page with a list of categories of items/offerings, and under each category name (Let's say one says sports) below you see a section that has pictures of the different items in that category that are available. Ultimately I do not even want to limit myself to 3 categories, I want to be able to expand it to be more categories, but 3 seemed like a good place to start.

Comment: And that last issue is really the main thing I'm trying to figure out, I'm not sure why it is that assigning the rows and columns the numbers I did - doesnt seem to have actually placed them in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured out what I'm doing wrong here. for CSS grid to work only the direct children elements of the grid will be grid items. So in this case I defined my columns with the goal of using them for nested elements inside of a grid item which will not work. I need to declare an additional grid or flexbox etc inside of my sections that contain the items.

And for my layout it looks like probably the easiest thing to do might be to make the main container (the grid) just have like 1 column and define my rows that take up the whole viewport width and then on the nested grids or flexbox for the items that is where I can work to specify their widths.

Comment: Yes I agree on this approach. An another approach that would be close to what you tried is to keep all your elements on the same DOM level. You have your grid container and inside it, title rows and content rows on the same level so that they are indeed part of the grid layout. Then you only need to place them where you want.